# About methods in OOP

Tags: oop, class, methods

I'm relatively new in OOP.

I understand classes, methods, etc, etc but I'm having troubles with the philosophy.

Right now, I'm working on a project to manage projects, with project management, class, methods, variables, users, groups, log and task management.

So, starting with `Project` class, i've that:

```
public function create_project()
public function get_projects()
public function delete_project()
```

Then, `ProjectClass` class:

```
public class create_class()
public class get_classes()
public class delete_class()
```

But then, I though that is not the right way, so I've changed to:

`Project` class methods:

set_name, get_name (and similar methods)
add_class
get_classes
add_log
get_logs

`ProjectClass` class methods:

set_project_id (and get)
add_variables (and get)
add_method
...

So, in the first case, is the `Project` class who create new projects, the `ProjectClass` class who creates the clases and the `Method` class who creates the methods, and in the second case, is the `Project` class who creates and manages its classes and is the `ProjectClass` class who creates and manages its methods.

So, is any of theses "styles" correct?

If is the second case the correct case, who creates the projects? Itself?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case it is really hard to tell if a design is better than the other if you don't have clear responsibilities to assign (and by this I mean behavior outside from getters and setters). As time went by I moved away from upfront design to a iterative/incremental one, tackling one problem at a time and refactoring the design as needed. In this case I would try to lay down the basic requirements of your system and start a design-implementation cycle for each of them, re-structuring your model as you go tackling new requirements.

Just an an example consider this question: Does it make sense to have a class that is not bounded to a project? If the answer is **no** then it can be a good idea to have a method like `Project>>createClass(aClassName)`, since you are explicitly stating that a class is created in the context of a project. Also you can make the proper connections between a class and the project it belongs to inside the method's implementation. However it is also a valid approach to define a constructor in the `ProjectClass` class that takes a project as a parameter. In that way you are saying "if you want to create a new class, then you must provide the project where it belongs to". Which approach to use depends on many things, one of them being programmer tastes :), so it is really hard to state if one is better than the other without having a specific context to evaluate them.

Finally, if it helps, there are a few things that are worth mentioning:

- Assuming that `public function create_project()` is an instance method, why does an instance of a `Project` know how to create other projects? At first it doesn't make much sense, since that is basically a class-side responsibility, unless you have a specific motivation for this (e.g. like the [Prototype](http://www.oodesign.com/prototype-pattern.html) pattern).
- Why does a project answer to `get_projects()`? Are they related in some way? Or it just list all the projects? Then again, this sounds like a class-side responsibility.
- I generally don't like to add the concept that the message receiver represents as part of the message. So, I wouldn't call the message `delete_project()`, since it is redundant to state `$project->delete_project()` (you already know the receiver of the message is a project).
- You should be consistent with your class names. If you use `ProjectClass` to represent classes then you should use `ProjectMethod` to represents methods (though I personally don't like these names, IMHO they are misleading). It is quite important to chose proper names and keep them consistent in your domain model.

HTH